# how to make bar chart?

Tags: iphone, xcode, charts

I am new to Iphone and i want to make bar chart can some one provide basic tutorial for it.I want make Simple line and small rectangle portion to show coordinate.
Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Try using [core-plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/).

Comment: hi I already try on corePlot but it's very tough and it's hard to understand is there any basic sample code so i can customise on my own .Thank You.

Comment: Thank You,For one of the best suggestion.But Can you please help me how can i draw rectangle in bar graph below x-axis.i tried core plot and i got success but i am unable to draw below x-axis in bar graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [DSBarChart](http://dhilipsiva.com/DSBarChart/). A simple Objective-C Bar Chart / Histogram library.

And here is the [sample usage](http://dhilipsiva.com/DSBarChart#sample-usage)